# String Concatenation in PHP using SQL

Tags: php, sql, concatenation

I am trying to create a login page where I have to link my database to the PHP code along with SQL query. I am using a SELECT and WHERE statement to assign the variable to the code, but it gives me a syntax error because I cannot concatenate the variables. Here's the code and please help me out.

$login = trim($_POST["id"]);

```
$password = trim($_POST["pass"]);

$conn = db_connect();


$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address, last_access FROM
users WHERE id = '".$login."' AND password = '".$password."'";

$results = pg_query($conn, $sql);

if(pg_num_rows($results))
{ 
   //not zero means something was found
   //user found, use pg_fetch_result to pull user specific info to display
   pg_fetch_result($results);

}
else
{
   //user not found, check for just login id
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$login."'";
   $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);
   if(!pg_num_rows($results))
   {  //user not found, empty $login to unstick it
      $login = ""; //when echo’’ed in the form
   }
}


?>
```

I can also show you a snip where the AND password part is showing in green color which means it is getting inside the double quotes and not working as an inbuilt function.

[image: You can see the green part which is getting inside the double quotes.]

Comment: Your `php` code is syntactically correct and the concatenation works. But you shouldn't take that approach. You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI` or `PDO` instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.  This is to avoid [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) but it also has the side benefit of allowing perfect syntax highlighting in your editor.

Comment: If you're receiving error it's not about the concatenation but something else. Please edit your question to share the code above/after this sql statement and the exact error.

Comment: Practice using prepared statements.

Comment: `This is to avoid SQL Injection attacks` .... which should be a big concern to you period, but even more so because you appear to be storing passwords in plain text!  Passwords should be hashed and never stored in plain text.